# What kind of diodes are these?

Tags: mosfet, diodes, components, voltage-divider

[image: image description here][image: image description here]

I think they are tvs diodes but i can't find what type they are.

Comment: Please, be more specific, what do you mean by "these". There are several components on those boards. The questions here on EE.SE must be useful also for other people browsing the site. People shouldn't be left wondering or guessing what you really mean. You should either describe what in those photos troubles you or edit those photos to mark the parts you are referring to.

Comment: Moreover, try to edit your photos so as not to waste that lot of space. Crop your photos to the right size. [There was recently a post on meta about just that](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6599/29434). It is still on the hot list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They look like LittleFuse TVS  diodes, LM is unidirectional and XM bidirectional.
[image]

[image]